# How to read PCIe complete register space in Linux terminal sysfs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pci-e

I am using Ubuntu and from terminal I am able to read the Type 0 Configuration space of PCIe by using "setpci", "lspci" or "pcimem". With both commands I am only able to read from 00h to 3Ch addresses. I want to read a specific register value whose address is D4h. As highlighted in the picture. Also by using "lspci -xxxx" it gives only hex data from 00h to 3Ch. I also attached the document, the pictures is of Table 3-8.

[image]

Reference:
https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/xeon-e5-1600-2600-vol-2-datasheet.pdf

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @jurez i am getting no error. but when i read from memory for example "lspci -xxxx" it only shows me hexadecimal data from 00 to 3C. Or if  i read using pcimem D4h, this return FFFF, which should be all zeros or atleast 0 on MSB.

Comment: You need to run lspci as root (e.g., with sudo).

Answer (score 1):

you can use below command to read any register in PCIe
setpci -s devicebus registerno

ex: setpci -s 02:00.0 d4.b  --> this will give value in register D4 specifying register width in byte(d4.b)